# Save/export plots from list of plots as single .png files

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, plot, lapply

I'm a bit stuck on this issue. I have this data obtained from a likert survey (so I make everything a factor):

```
df1<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,2,3,4,5,1,1,2,3),
              B=c(4,4,2,3,4,2,1,5,2,2),
              C=c(3,3,3,3,4,2,5,1,2,3),
              D=c(1,2,5,5,5,4,5,5,2,3),
              E=c(1,4,2,3,4,2,5,1,2,3),
              dummy1=c("yes","yes","no","no","no","no","yes","no","yes","yes"),
              dummy2=c("high","low","low","low","high","high","high","low","low","high"))

df1[colnames(df1)] <- lapply(df1[colnames(df1)], factor)
```

I then create a list of dataframes to be used in each plot:

```
vals <- colnames(df1)[1:5]
dummies <- colnames(df1)[-(1:5)]
step1 <- lapply(dummies, function(x) df1[, c(vals, x)])
step2 <- lapply(step1, function(x) split(x, x[, 6]))
names(step2) <- dummies
tbls <- unlist(step2, recursive=FALSE)
tbls<-lapply(tbls, function(x) x[(names(x) %in% names(df1[c(1:5)]))])
```

This is the plotting function I made (I used the `likert` package)

```
plot_likert <- function(x){
  
  y<-deparse(substitute(x))
  y<-sub("\\$", " - ",y)
  
  p<-plot(likert(x),
          type ="bar",center=3,
          group.order=names(x))+
    labs(x = "Theme", subtitle=paste("Number of observations:",nrow(x)))+ 
    guides(fill=guide_legend("Rank"))+
    ggtitle(paste("How do they rank? -",gsub("\\.",": ",y)))
  
  png(filename=paste("Ranking -",y,".png"), width = 3000, height = 2000, res=300)
  print(p)
  dev.off()
}
```

So that now I can make the plot by writing:

```
plot_likert(tbls$dummy1.no)
```

Finally, I apply the function over the whole table by using

```
lapply(tbls,function(x) {
  y<-deparse(substitute(x))
  y<-sub("\\$", " - ",y)
  
  plot(likert(x),
          type ="bar",center=3,
          group.order=names(x))+
    labs(x = "Theme", subtitle=paste("Number of observations:",nrow(x)))+ 
    guides(fill=guide_legend("Rank"))+
    ggtitle(paste("How do these themes rank? -",gsub("\\.",": ",y)))
}) -> list_plots
```

But now I don't know how to save each graph in the list as a separate .png file! I managed to put everything in a pdf like this, but it's not what I actually want:

```
ggsave(
  filename = "plots.pdf", 
  plot = marrangeGrob(list_plots, nrow=1, ncol=1), 
  width = 15, height = 9
)
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this? Also, if you have anything to add about my function/procedure overall, everything is welcome! I'm still quite new to R.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can use:

```
sapply(1:length(list_plots), function(i) ggsave(
  filename = paste0("plots ",i,".pdf"), 
  plot = list_plots[[i]], 
  width = 15, height = 9
))
```

---

For names: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73370416/5224236

```
mynames <- sapply(names(tbls), function(x) {
  paste("How do they rank? -",gsub("\\.",": ",x))
})

myfilenames <- names(tbls)

plot_likert <- function(x, myname, myfilename){
  p <- plot(likert(x),
          type ="bar",center=3,
          group.order=names(x))+
    labs(x = "Theme", subtitle=paste("Number of observations:",nrow(x)))+ 
    guides(fill=guide_legend("Rank"))+
    ggtitle(myname)
  p
}

list_plots <- lapply(1:length(tbls),function(i) {
  plot_likert(tbls[[i]], mynames[i], myfilenames[i])
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, using this I just get this output `[1] "plots 1.pdf" "plots 2.pdf" "plots 3.pdf" "plots 4.pdf"`, but no files are actually created. Any idea why?
Also, I imagine this solution creates .pdf files, is there any way to create standalone .png /.jpeg files?

Comment: What is your working directory? Yes just replace png inside the code

Comment: Nevermind, changing from .pdf to .png works for some reason now! Also, I think there's a final closing parenthesis missing, but can't edit it because it's too short an edit.

One final issue that I think has to do with my plotting function... In the exported plot the title becomes **"How do these themes rank? - X[[i]]"**  instead of **"How do these themes rank? - dummy: 1"** as specified in the function in these lines: `y<-deparse(substitute(x))
  y<-sub("\\$", " - ",y)` and `ggtitle(paste("How do these themes rank? -",gsub("\\.",": ",y)))`. Do you maybe have suggestion on this? Thx again!

Comment: see the answer edits