# Change title of plots in list

Tags: r, list, function, ggplot2, apply

I have a problem with my plotting function. I already asked kind of a similar question and [Here are all the data and the plotting function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73363941/r-save-export-plots-from-list-of-plots-as-single-png-files).

When I try to apply my plotting function to my list of dfs, the title gets changed and the title condition I specified in the function is not respected. Is there a way to rename all the plots in the list or fix the function/loop so that the title stays the same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't shown your actual *vs.* expected result, but at a glance I'd guess that `deparse(substitute(x))` doesn't do anything useful when the function is called inside `lapply` or similar, since `x` will have the name of the variable inside the `lapply` function (i.e. it will be something like `x`, not `tbls$dummy1.no`). The simplest fix, then, would be to add an additional parameter to your function which takes the name. Then you can replace `lapply(…)` by `Map(plot_likert, tbls, names(tbls))`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Right now, when I launch `lapply` i get **"How do these themes rank? - X[[i]]"** but what I want is **"How do these themes rank? - dummy: 1"**, with the second part of the title (dummy: 1, in this case) changing accordingly with the df plotted. 
Concerning your suggestion, doesn't the `y` in the function work as the additional parameter? Or do I need to add another one? What would you add as fix? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `y` currently isn't a function parameter, it's a local variable! You're using `substitute(x)` to find the name of the argument `x` in the calling scope, but the calling scope is *inside the function `lapply`), and as you can see `lapply` is calling your function with the expression `x[[i]]`, so that's the value that `y` gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as intended:

```
mynames <- sapply(names(tbls), function(x) {
  paste("How do they rank? -",gsub("\\.",": ",x))
})

myfilenames <- names(tbls)

plot_likert <- function(x, myname, myfilename){
  p <- plot(likert(x),
          type ="bar",center=3,
          group.order=names(x))+
    labs(x = "Theme", subtitle=paste("Number of observations:",nrow(x)))+ 
    guides(fill=guide_legend("Rank"))+
    ggtitle(myname)
  p
}

list_plots <- lapply(1:length(tbls),function(i) {
  plot_likert(tbls[[i]], mynames[i], myfilenames[i])
})
```

[image]

When in doubt, keep things stupid and simple. Non-standard evaluation like `deparse(substitute(` will throw you right into Burns' [R inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! One last question, I'm want to modify `mynames` code so that each graph has a fully automated title like so: 

`mynames <- sapply(names(tbls), function(x) {
  paste("How do", section,"rank? -",gsub("\\.",": ",x))
})`
Where `section` is a list of strings like this one `section<-c("Tech","Social","Law")`. In my real data, the name of the dfs matches part of this string, so is it possible to have each plot title match its section without using `deparse`? So if the name of the df used is `Technology` the resulting title is **How does Technology rank? - dummy2: low**

Comment: I'll take a look later

Comment: Or better still, would there be a way to use `if` statements within this series of functions so that if I specify `Likert_plot_section(section=="Tech")` I then get the list of plots corresponding to the Tech section?

Comment: For a clearer explanation of what I'm aiming at check this if you'd like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73384165/r-plot-function-by-condition-and-subsample-for-factor-data